# Como impedir o auto-redirect de http para https?

Tags: linux, apache, docker

Meu container web de desenvolvimento utiliza a imagem **php:7.1-apache**. Para ficar mais fácil de memorizar o endereço das aplicações contidas neste container, gosto de editar o arquivo Hosts da minha máquina e fazer o apontamento desta forma:

```
127.0.0.1   site.dev
```

Entretanto, recentemente passei a ter dificuldades com essa abordagem, parece que os navegadores passaram recentemente a forçar o HTTPS, ou seja, sou redirecionado e consequentemente caio em uma página de erro do próprio navegador já que o SSL não está configurado no server apache que roda no container.

Alguma solução para isso, que não seja configurar SSL?

O sistema hospedeiro que roda o container é um Mac OS (ultima versão estável)

Segue os dados para montar o container:

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: senha_root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: banco
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: senha_user
    command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/tmp:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-web
    volumes:
      - ./projetos/:/var/www
      - ./apache/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
    working_dir: /var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure #always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

MAINTAINER Fabio J L Ferreira <fabiojaniolima@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update; \
    a2enmod rewrite; \
    apt-get install -y curl unzip git npm libpng-dev; \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -; \
    apt-get install -y nodejs; \
    echo "America/Sao_Paulo" > /etc/timezone; \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer

# Install PHP "gd" extension
# RUN apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev
# RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && docker-php-ext-install gd

# Instala a extensão PHP "exif" => http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.exif.php
# RUN apt-get install -y libexif-dev && RUN docker-php-ext-install exif

# Extensão "mysqi" e algumas "PDO" => http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev; \
    docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql; \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*

COPY php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conforme o https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/ e o https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/669923

Desde o Chrome 63 (Dezembro de 2017), irá forcar todos domínios terminados em `.dev` (e `.foo`) serem redirecionados para HTTPS pre-carregados com o header HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), o que irá permitir usar o dominio `*.dev` para desenvolvimento (agora creio ser `*.test` o usado).

Existe também a proposta de usar `*.localhost` para apontar sempre para o 127.0.0.1 como padrão em https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-let-localhost-be-localhost-06

> **Nota:** o AP confirmou que o dominio `*.local` funcionou para o caso dele, mudando no hosts para
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 site.local
> ```
>
> estarei editando a resposta com mais detalhes sobre estes dominios .dev, .local, .foo

Comment: @Bacco sim no link que postei fala o mesmo que você inclusive, foi erro meu, mas sabe como é zilhões de pessoas podem ensinar e fazer errado que tá tudo bem :) (desculpe cara, tem coisa que sinceramente é dificil -.-) ... ps: prometo revisar e corrigir a resposta :)

Answer (score 4):

Isso dependerá do navegador em uso.

Aparentemente o Chrome é o único que permite a utilização de um localhost sem SSL via a seguinte *flag*:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Comment: A dica é otima! +1 ... Só tem um problema, ele esta acessando, após configurar o hosts, o endereço `site.dev`, provavelmente um exemplo, eu suponho que seja o endereço do site em produção que quando acessado na máquina diretamente será visto o local. Mas vou aguardar o AP pra ter certeza :)

Comment: Como o @GuilhermeNascimentoP. explicou, eu criei um endereço de exemplo no hosts, ou seja, chamo site.dev (exemplo) e este me redireciona para 127.0.0.1 com esse parâmetro na requisição, quando o server captura a requisição sabe que deve carregar o virtualhosts site.dev (em outras palavras, preciso fazer isso mas sem ser redirecionado de http para https, sempre consegui este comportamento, porém, recentemente voltei a desenvolver e notei que tem um redirect que eu não configurei)

Comment: Fábio - entendo (obrigado por clarificar @GuilhermeNascimentoP.) - acho que neste caso infelizmente um certificado, mesmo auto-assinado, será necessário. =/

Comment: Por qual motivo isso ocorre, será que pelo fato do endereço 127.0.0.1 está sendo chamado por baixo dos panos? Pois não faria sentido falar que o navegador está forçando https (só por falar) pois acesso páginas http em domínios reais sem problema algum.

Comment: Ono e @FábioJânio não pude testar ou ler tudo sobre o assunto mas creio que isto talvez ajude https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/ (se for .dev ou .foo)

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimentoP. resolvi o problema. Após ler a conteúdo contida no link que você indicou, alterei os endereços de *.dev para *.local e obtive sucesso.

Comment: Excelente noticia! @GuilhermeNascimentoP. poste como resposta para que o Fabio possa aceitar. =)

Comment: @OnoSendai irei fazer ;) é que realmente estava sem tempo, obrigado